# User Generated Content using Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I am developing a simple HTML5 app for a television station that should allow users of the app to capture or upload video content and submit it in for moderation. This content can then be published as news from Citizen journalists.

I am interested in using the Youtube API, however, can it offer me the following key functionality that I need:

```
a) Ability of a user to upload video content for moderation
b) Ability of a moderator to review the content and publish it, moderator should have ability to view all videos on the application.include comments and publish it.
```

I am looking at the API to offer me functionality like the CNN ireport app

Part of the reason I also want to use Youtube is because of it's large storage capacity for video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) for this. At least that is the technology choice I would have considered if I were you. It has tight coupling to the youtube API and you can choose your implementation language: Python, Go, Java or PHP and you also will not have the lockin to youtube since you can with GAE allow users to upload videos to the google cloud if you use google appengine.

Comment: Thank you @Nick Rtz How would you compare this with Daily motion cloud.